# Using Wifi WPS automation in app

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, router, wifi-protected-setup

I'm working on a home project and im trying to open my network programmatically!
Is there any way to simulate pressing the WPS button from an app?
My aim is to write an app where on a click of a button it would simulate pressing the WPS key on my home router for 30 seconds.

Comment: This question is a little bit broad. Give us some more details. What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press the WPS button on your home router, you are completing a circuit that tells the router to emit a signal allowing nearby devices to connect. There is no remote method to control this physical mechanism & that is why it is recommended as a secure set-up.

In order to automate this process you will need to disable push button control through your router's configuration page. Unfortunately, this could make your network vulnerable to WPS brute-force attacks. I highly recommend you disable WPS altogether & use a strong WPA/2 passphrase if you don't want to connect using WPS-Push Button Control.